# Bind JSON to view (SAPUI5) with model name

Tags: json, xml, sapui5

If I want to bind JSON to view:

XML:

```
<m:Input id="name" value="{/name}" enabled="false"/>
```

controller:

```
var data = {name : "name"};
var oModel = new JSONModel(data);
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

and how to bind JSON to view with spesified model name?

controller :

```
var data = {name : "name"};
var oModel = new JSONModel(data, "data");
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

how to code in xml? I try this but not bind.

```
<m:Input id="name" value="{data>/name}" enabled="false"/>
```

because I want to bind with 2 source json data, if i set with spesified model name, just one model bind to view.

Thanks,
Bobby

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible to bind n numbers of models to the view. You can specify the alias with which model is bound to the view ( or any control). You do not specify alias while creating model but at the time of setting the model to the control ( like view).

So, this is wrong:

```
var data = {name : "name"};
var oModel = new JSONModel(data, "data"); // Alias is not specified here
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

Correct code is :

```
var data = {name : "name"};
var oModel = new JSONModel(data); // Only set data here.
this.getView().setModel(oModel, "data"); // set the alias here
```

Similarly,

```
var data = {employeeName: "Rahul"};
var oModel = new JSONModel(data); // Only set data here.
this.getView().setModel(oModel, "EmployeeData"); // set the alias here
```

And in View,

```
<m:Input id="name" value="{data>/name}" enabled="false" description="{EmployeeData>/employeeName}"/>
<m:Input id="name" value="{EmployeeData>/employeeName}" enabled="false"/>
```

Comment: I should try this but not bind.. I try with this to table or other component, no problem. thanks

Comment: Now I could bind with model name thanks. But another question is when I use List control , how do I bind value on the StandListItem? Can't display title and id on items.
e.g
   <List id="dialogListMpn" headerText="MPN" items="{onDialogMpnSearch>/albums}">
    <StandardListItem title="{title}" description="{id}" type="Active" press="onMpnItemPress"/>
   </List>

Comment: You will have to use the Model alias name which you bound your List to. ie. `<List id="dialogListMpn" headerText="MPN" items="{onDialogMpnSearch>/albums}"> <StandardListItem title="{onDialogMpnSearch>title}" description="{onDialogMpnSearch>id}" type="Active" press="onMpnItemPress"/> </List>`. Model name has to be specified for every binding to that model. If you don't specify, it will try to fetch from un-named model.